# Display a VisualBrush from a hidden control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I got the following xaml

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TextBlock x:Name="_sampleText"
           Grid.Row="0"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           Width="200" 
           Height="50"
           FontSize="36"
           Text="Hello world"
           TextAlignment="Center"
           Visibility="Collapsed" />

<Border Grid.Row="1" 
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=_sampleText}" 
        Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=_sampleText}">
  <Border.Background>
    <VisualBrush Stretch="None" 
                 Visual="{Binding ElementName=_sampleText}" />
  </Border.Background>
</Border>
</Grid>
```

I want my visual to be render even if the control he bind too is not visible. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also place the TextBlock in a Border and make that `Hidden`:

```
<Border Visibility="Hidden">
    <TextBlock ... />
</Border>
```

Comment: `<Canvas Opacity="0">` also works well as an invisiable container.

Comment: Or any other Panel of course. Or `<Border Opacity="0">`, too. It's your choice, but the visual effect is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the `Visibility=Collapsed` then it won't take part in the measure/arrange layout pass and not be rendered (the `Width` and `Height` will be 0).

What effect are you trying to achieve? It looks like you want a preview pane? Reply in the comments and we can figure out the best approach.

**Edit:** There is a way to call the measure/update on a `UIElement` from code-behind however I think the best-approach for you would be use a `BoolToVisibilityConverter`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox x:Name="OptionCheckBox" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=OptionCheckBox", Converter={StaticResouce BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"> 
        <TextBlock Width="200" Height="50" FontSize="36" Text="Hello world" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is there a way to call measure/arrange without rendering (on screen) the control? Yes, it's something like a preview pane. It's an option page where the user can say: yes, I want to show that control (or not) and I try to preview what the control would look like. If the control is already visible and the user say I don't want to see it again, that's easy but for the inverse, it's doesn't work...

Comment: @Melursus: Updated my answer in response to your comment. ... That should do what you want. If you have many different type of controls to be previewed, then I would put a `ContentControl` in your preview pane and then use a `DataTemplate`.